# Can't access virtualhosts on Centos/apache

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I'm running a CentOS 6.8 server using VMWare Fusion and I've got my Apache up and running, though I'm unable to access any virtual hosts.  I followed this walkthrough (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6) though I also tried using Webmin to no avail. Apache stops/restarts without error and I don't see anything in /var/log/httpd/error_log.  Here's the end of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/relynx.dev/public_html
        ServerName relynx.dev
        ServerAlias www.relynx.dev
        ErrorLog /var/www/relynx.dev/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you need to check two things :

1- your firewall

```
 service iptables status
```

And see if there's an open port for 80

2- check your dns :

See if you have set the domain name of your server in "hosts" file.

```
(ip@)192.168.56.x  relynx.dev
```

Or you can just use the ip@ insted of domain-name in apache.